# python TypeVar Reset in Tuple

Tags: python, typing, python-typing

I have a problem with my `TypeVar` definition.
My function requires a tuple of tuples as a parameter. The main tuple can have as many as tuples as components but they don't have to share the same type between them.
But the component of the tuple inside the main tuple have to share the same type.

Here a simplified example of code:
The following code work in python but I have a warning in Pycharm

```python
form((("prompt", str, "default"),
      ("prompt", int, 10),
      ("prompt", str, "default"),
      ("prompt", float, .5)))
```

[image: PyCharm Warning]

I defined my function like that:

```python
ValueType = TypeVar('ValueType', str, int, float, bool)
InputDefinitionType = Tuple[str, Type[ValueType], ValueType]

def form(input_def: Tuple[InputDefinitionType, ...])
    ...
```

How can I 'reset' the TypeVar group to only match the types inside the tuple contained inside the main tuple **but not across** the main tuple itself?

Comment: Interestingly, MyPy seems very happy with your current annotations — but I'm not entirely sure whether that means there's a MyPy bug or a Pycharm bug https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-context&gist=7beb65f5ef8715d0e73cfcdbb4ebdae0

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:** The way you're implementing it is wrong, but there's a workaround at the bottom of this answer.

Unfortunately, your code does not type-check. A constrained type variable must refer to the same type within a given "scope" ([PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#scoping-rules-for-type-variables) has some definitions on scope but it's not too precise).

In your case, `ValueType` must refer to a single type within the `form` function, so your call is not valid.

---

As to why the code seems to type-check in mypy, it's because `InputDefinitionType` is a [generic type alias](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-type-aliases), but you're using it without parameterization, which is then equivalent to parameterizing with `Any`. Put simply:

```
def form(input_def: Tuple[InputDefinitionType, ...]) -> None: ...
```

is equivalent to

```
def form(input_def: Tuple[InputDefinitionType[Any], ...]) -> None: ...
```

You can see this in [mypy-play](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-context&gist=7c13e966089e91b4e0f4944912f14494), where the final `reveal_type(form)` shows the inferred type of the function to be:

```
main.py:15: note: Revealed type is "def (input_def: builtins.tuple[Tuple[builtins.str, Type[Any], Any]])"
```

---

A workaround for this is to turn it into a `Union` type:

```
ValueType = TypeVar('ValueType')
InputDef = Tuple[str, Type[ValueType], ValueType]  # name shortened for conciseness
InputDefConcrete = Union[
  InputDef[float], InputDef[str], InputDef[bool], InputDef[int]
]

def form(input_def: Tuple[InputDefConcrete, ...]) -> None: ...
```

See it in action on [mypy-play](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=0ab0fd7dc1829c7da1178c8e72ac24e5).